# JavaFX - поместить TitledPane вовнутрь Accordion (SceneBuilder)

Tags: java, javafx

Исходные данные:
есть основа RootLayout.fxml:

```
--BorderPane 
.....|--insert TOP 
.............|--MenuBar 
.....|--insert CENTER 
.............|--Accordion 
.....|-- {...}
```

есть TeamOverview.fxml:

```
--TitledPane 
......|--AnchorPane 
...........|--SplitPane 
.................|-- {...}
```

---

в классе Main инициализирую

```
 public void initRootLayout() {

    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        // todo
         //rootLayout = (BorderPane)loader.load();
        rootLayoutAccordion = loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(rootLayoutAccordion);
        // ---------

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

выбивает ошибку:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane cannot be cast to
>   javafx.scene.control.Accordion

Подробнее класс *Mine* здесь [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/21gFu9ZF)

Что я хочу? Уйти от ошибки компиляции и смочь вызывать другие вкладки в `RootLayout`, у меня их еще три. Работы продолжаю, если закончу раньше, чем получу ответ - распишу здесь.

открыл доступ к репозиторию [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/Sergey_Lakhnov/strateghelper/overview)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Andrew Bystrov за толчок в верном направлении.
Рабочие методы:

```
public void initRootLayout() {

       try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));

            rootLayout = loader.load();
           Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);

           // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

и метод, позволяющий добавлять вкладки:

```
public void showAccordion() {

        try {
            // Load team overview.
            FXMLLoader loaderTeamOverview = new FXMLLoader();
            loaderTeamOverview.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/TeamOverview.fxml"));

            // Load CartOverview
            FXMLLoader loaderCartOverview = new FXMLLoader();
            loaderCartOverview.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/CartOverview.fxml"));


            TitledPane teamOverviewTitledPane = loaderTeamOverview.load();
            TitledPane cartOverviewTitledPane = loaderCartOverview.load() ;

            // Add Titled Pane to Accordion
            Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

            accordion.getPanes().addAll(teamOverviewTitledPane,cartOverviewTitledPane);

            // Set accordion to Center

            rootLayout.setCenter(accordion);

            //Give the controller acces to the main app.

            TeamOverviewController teamOverviewController = loaderTeamOverview.getController();

            teamOverviewController.setMain(this);


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так. Я думаю тебе это поможет.

```
public void initRootLayout() {

    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        rootLayoutAccordion.getPanes().add(new TitledPane("root", pane);
        rootLayout.setCenter(rootLayoutAccordion);
        // ---------

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Вот так вот тебе надо сделать методы ( насколько я смог понять)

```
 public void initRootLayout() {

    try {
        this.rootLayoutAccordion = new Accordion();
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        rootLayoutAccordion.getPanes().add(new TitledPane("root", pane);
        rootLayout.setCenter(rootLayoutAccordion);
        // ---------

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void showTeamOverview() {

        try {
            // Load person overview.

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/TeamOverview.fxml"));
//            AnchorPane teamOverview =  loader.load();
            TitledPane teamOverviewTitledPane = loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            // todo Alternative
            rootLayoutAccordion.getPanes().add(teamOverviewTitledPane);

                rootLayoutAccordion.setExpandedPane(teamOverviewTitledPane);


            //Give the controller acces to the main app.

            TeamOverviewController controller = loader.getController();

            controller.setMain(this);


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: rootLayoutAccordion.getPanes().add(new TitledPane("root", pane)); - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at strateghelper.Main.initRootLayout(Main.java:112)

Comment: А у тебя rootLayoutAccordion создана? ты где нибудь делал rootLayoutAccorion = new Accordion() ?

Comment: весь класс Mine лежит по ссылке на Pastebin, указанной в теле вопроса, посмотри там, пожалуйста.

Comment: См ответ, там апдейт

Comment: опять Null pointer exception. Дебажил - rootLayout постоянно Null. BitBucket: https://Sergey_Lakhnov@bitbucket.org/Sergey_Lakhnov/strateghelper.git

Comment: открыл общий доступ к битбакету. По возможности, глянь, пожалуйста, ветку easyway. Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/Sergey_Lakhnov/strateghelper/src/13e4a3e636c801b9819faac6c78f96050d8ee6ea/src/easy/Main.java?at=easyway&fileviewer=file-view-default

73 строчка - лишняя, потому как если ты загружаешь что-то из fxml, то это не надо инициализировать. Инициализация происходит автоматически при методе load().

метод showAccordion()

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/TeamOverview.fxml"));
rootLayoutTitledPane = loader.load();

Comment: у тебя rootLayoutTitledPane объявлена как TitledPane, а в файле view/TeamOverview.fxml у тебя рутовый элемент - AnchorPane. Надо выбрать что-то одно - либо объявить rootLayoutTitledPane типа AnchorPane, или в fxml сделать рутовым элементом TitledPane

Comment: использовал твои рекомендации - частично получилось. Но  теперь выдает _javafx.fxml.LoadException_ на _TeamOverview.fxml_. Не могу понять, в чем дело.

Comment: механическая опечатка в _TeamOverview.fxml_ - исправил и заработало.